# Gstreamer playbin cannot play IPCamera mjpeg rtsp 2048x1534

Tags: gstreamer, mjpeg

Gstreamer playbin cannot play my IPCamera mjpeg rtsp with 2048x1534 resolution:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.100:554/1/1
```

It shows the following WARNING message:

```
WARNING: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstRtpJPEGDepay:rtpjpegdepay0: Invalid Dimension 0x1536.
```

I have also test the following pipeline to force video size:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.100:554/1/1 ! application/x-rtp,media="video",width=2048,height=1536 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

but it complains similar WARNING message.

It should be note that when I change my video encoding to H.264 from camera panel everything is OK with playbin!

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323756/gstreamer-error-when-streaming-side-by-side-720p/56393777#56393777